# service was unable to place a task because no container instance met requirements. The closest matching container-instance has insufficient CPU units

Tags: amazon-ec2, containers, terraform

I am trying to run 2 tasks on the same EC2 container. The EC2 container is running on a `t2.large` type EC2 instance. 
One of the tasks (which is a daemon) starts fine and is `RUNNING`.
The other task which is an application, does not start and I see the following errors in the Events tab.

```
service test-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance xxxxxx has insufficient CPU units available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.

service test-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance xxxxxx has insufficient memory available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.
```

I looked at the CPU and memory section for the container instance and the values are -

```
       Registered  Available
CPU    1024         1014
Memory  985         729
```

My task definitions for the task that does not run has the following CPU and Memory values -

```
    "memory": 512,
    "cpu": 10
```

The daemon that successfully runs on the same EC2 container instance also has the same values for memory and CPU.

I read thru the AWS docs here at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-instance-requirement-error/ and tried to reduce the CPU and memory requirements for the test-service task definition but nothing helped. I also changed the instance type to something bigger but that did not help either.

Can someone please help me with what I should do CPU and memory for both the tasks (daemon and application) so they can run on the same EC2 container instance ?

Note: I cannot add another container to the ECS cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The task definition sets CPU limit to 10 units which is probably insufficient in your case. ECS can manage CPU resources dynamically when you set up the value to 0. However it is not possible in case of memory.

Comment: Cannot set CPU value to 0: `The CPU value is not valid. The valid values are .125 vCPU - 10 vCPU.`